# How to solve "RuntimeError: Expected target size [6, 1, 224, 224], got [6, 3, 224, 224]"?

Tags: pytorch, neural-network

I got this error in DeepCrack. I tried to solve it with several searches but I didn't find any solutions. How can I overcome the target size issue? Firstly, I faced tensor tuple issues, but I applied a stack that solve the tuple problem. Now, I don't understand the size fitting. I don't what is actual size here of CNN is. Can anyone please help me?

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import numpy as np
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
from torch.utils.data import random_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os
import copy

cudnn.benchmark = True
plt.ion()   # interactive mode

from random import *
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm, trange
from time import sleep
from pathlib import Path
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import transforms, models
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')

  
# functions to show an image

def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('labels.JPG')
    
##  codes for data augmentation
train_trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5), ## tamim: image will move left and right
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(p=0.5), ## tamim: image will come to eye vertically
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=(.5, 5)), ## very small rotation of the cracks
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    )
])


test_trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5), ## tamim: image will move left and right
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(p=0.5), ## tamim: image will come to eye vertically
    transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=(.5, 5)), ## very small rotation of the cracks
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
        std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    )
])


## Load data
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
data = ImageFolder('../Data/Data_Structure(Annotated)', transform=train_trans , )
test_folder= ImageFolder("../Data/DATA_iPhone_13_Pro_Max", transform=test_trans, )


batch_size = 6
num_classes = 4
learning_rate = 0.01
num_epochs = 10

print("Follwing classes are there : \n",data.classes)

classes = ('Alligator Cracks', 'Delamination', 'Longitudinal Cracks', 'Transverse Cracks')

len(data)

##Splitting Data and Prepare Batches: 
## Source: https://medium.com/thecyphy/train-cnn-model-with-pytorch-21dafb918f48 
val_size = 127 ##  Tamim:30% data for validation ## 
train_size = len(data) - val_size 


train_loader,val_loader = random_split(data,[train_size,val_size]) ## To randomly split the images into training and testing, PyTorch provides random_split()
print(f"Length of Train Data : {len(train_loader)}")                   ## changed the folder names
print(f"Length of Validation Data : {len(val_loader)}")

# Splitting train and validation data on batches

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_loader, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size) ## defined train data & val data
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_loader, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_folder, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)


# visualize images of a single batch

dataiter = iter(train_loader)
images, labels = next(dataiter)

# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
# print labels
print(' '.join(f'{classes[labels[j]]:5s}' for j in range(batch_size)))


# model = models.vgg19(pretrained=True)
# print(model)

from torch import nn
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


def Conv3X3(in_, out):
    return torch.nn.Conv2d(in_, out, 3, padding=1)


class ConvRelu(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_, out):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = Conv3X3(in_, out)
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        return x

class Down(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, nn):
        super(Down,self).__init__()
        self.nn = nn
        self.maxpool_with_argmax = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

    def forward(self,inputs):
        down = self.nn(inputs)
        unpooled_shape = down.size()
        outputs, indices = self.maxpool_with_argmax(down)
        return outputs, down, indices, unpooled_shape

class Up(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, nn):
        super().__init__()
        self.nn = nn
        self.unpool=torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d(2,2)

    def forward(self,inputs,indices,output_shape):
        outputs = self.unpool(inputs, indices=indices, output_size=output_shape)
        outputs = self.nn(outputs)
        return outputs

class Fuse(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, nn, scale):
        super().__init__()
        self.nn = nn
        self.scale = scale
        self.conv = Conv3X3(64,1) 

    def forward(self,down_inp,up_inp):
        outputs = torch.cat([down_inp, up_inp], 1) 
        outputs = F.interpolate(outputs, scale_factor=self.scale, mode='bilinear')
        outputs = self.nn(outputs)

        return self.conv(outputs)



class DeepCrack(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, num_classes=1000):
        super(DeepCrack, self).__init__()

        self.down1 = Down(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(3,64),
            ConvRelu(64,64),
        ))

        self.down2 = Down(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(64,128),
            ConvRelu(128,128),
        ))

        self.down3 = Down(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(128,256),
            ConvRelu(256,256),
            ConvRelu(256,256),
        ))

        self.down4 = Down(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(256, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
        ))

        self.down5 = Down(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
        ))

        self.up1 = Up(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(64, 64),
            ConvRelu(64, 64),
        ))

        self.up2 = Up(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(128, 128),
            ConvRelu(128, 64),
        ))

        self.up3 = Up(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(256, 256),
            ConvRelu(256, 256),
            ConvRelu(256, 128),
        ))

        self.up4 = Up(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 256),
        ))

        self.up5 = Up(torch.nn.Sequential(
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
            ConvRelu(512, 512),
        ))

        self.fuse5 = Fuse(ConvRelu(512 + 512, 64), scale=16)
        self.fuse4 = Fuse(ConvRelu(512 + 256, 64), scale=8)
        self.fuse3 = Fuse(ConvRelu(256 + 128, 64), scale=4)
        self.fuse2 = Fuse(ConvRelu(128 + 64, 64), scale=2)
        self.fuse1 = Fuse(ConvRelu(64 + 64, 64), scale=1)

        self.final = Conv3X3(5,1)

    def forward(self,inputs):

        # encoder part
        out, down1, indices_1, unpool_shape1 = self.down1(inputs)
        out, down2, indices_2, unpool_shape2 = self.down2(out)
        out, down3, indices_3, unpool_shape3 = self.down3(out)
        out, down4, indices_4, unpool_shape4 = self.down4(out)
        out, down5, indices_5, unpool_shape5 = self.down5(out)

        # decoder part
        up5 = self.up5(out, indices=indices_5, output_shape=unpool_shape5)
        up4 = self.up4(up5, indices=indices_4, output_shape=unpool_shape4)
        up3 = self.up3(up4, indices=indices_3, output_shape=unpool_shape3)
        up2 = self.up2(up3, indices=indices_2, output_shape=unpool_shape2)
        up1 = self.up1(up2, indices=indices_1, output_shape=unpool_shape1)

        fuse5 = self.fuse5(down_inp=down5,up_inp=up5)
        fuse4 = self.fuse4(down_inp=down4, up_inp=up4)
        fuse3 = self.fuse3(down_inp=down3, up_inp=up3)
        fuse2 = self.fuse2(down_inp=down2, up_inp=up2)
        fuse1 = self.fuse1(down_inp=down1, up_inp=up1)

        output = self.final(torch.cat([fuse5,fuse4,fuse3,fuse2,fuse1],1))

        return output, fuse5, fuse4, fuse3, fuse2, fuse1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inp = torch.randn((1,3,512,512)) 

    model = DeepCrack()

    out = model(inp)
    
model = DeepCrack()

print(model)

# specify loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# specify loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# number of epochs to train the model
n_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
    # monitor training loss
    train_loss = 0.0
    
    ###################
    # train the model #
    ###################
    for data in train_loader:
        # _ stands in for labels, here
        # no need to flatten images
        images, _ = data
        # clear the gradients of all optimized variables
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # forward pass: compute predicted outputs by passing inputs to the model
        outputs = model(images)
        outputs = torch.stack(outputs, dim=0, out=None) ## Tamim: converted the tuple of tensors to one.
        outputs = outputs ## Changed shape
        print(outputs.shape) ## Tamim: printed the target tensor shape to see
        print(outputs) ## Tamim: printed the target tensors
        # calculate the loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, images)
        # backward pass: compute gradient of the loss with respect to model parameters
        loss.backward()
        # perform a single optimization step (parameter update)
        optimizer.step()
        # update running training loss
        train_loss += loss.item()*images.size(0)
            
    # print avg training statistics 
    train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader)
    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch, 
        train_loss
        ))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_deepcrack.py", line 324, in <module>
    loss = criterion(outputs, images)
  File "/apps/pkg/pytorch/1.10.2/cuda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/pkg/pytorch/1.10.2/cuda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1150, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/apps/pkg/pytorch/1.10.2/cuda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2846, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: Expected target size [6, 1, 224, 224], got [6, 3, 224, 224]
```

Comment: I suspect your annotations (targets) are being loaded as 3-channel (RGB) color images whereas your model outputs a single binary classification probability map (i.e. your model is a binary classifier but the target shape suggests a multiclass classification problem). However, you need to include the model definition code, the dataset definition code, print the tensor sizes of the output, target and input, and include the code where you call the model. This code is necessary to provide meaningful feedback on your problem

Comment: @DerekG thank you for your comment. I don't understand what you mean by model definition code and dataset definition code. If you look at my code, you will notice that I preprocessed data and defined the model. The model is DeepCrack CNN. that I took from Github.  My data structure is (Main_Folder -- Folder_class 1 - (images), Folder_class 2- (images), Folder_class 3 - (images), Folder_class 4- (images)).

Comment: Ah I see, in that case it would be good to show the print outputs that indicate the size of various tensors. Can you print out the console outputs prior to the error?

Comment: I changed the image size 512 x 512 from 224 x 224. So, now input and output shapes are torch.Size([6, 3, 512, 512]) = input or images and  torch.Size([6, 6, 1, 512, 512]) = outputs. I'm wondered because output shape has 5 elements while input has 4.